# Suppose that $f ' (x)$ exists and $f(x)$ has two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$. Try to prove that:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Suppose that  $f'(x)$ exists and $f(x)$ has two roots $x_1$ and $x_2$. Try to prove that:

> $\exists \xi \in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(\xi)+f'(\xi)=0$.

We cannot use the knowedge of integration.

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. Please check it.

Comment: Are you trying to say that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ and $f(x)$ has tw roots $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Consider $\phi(x)=e^xf(x)$ which is  continuous and differentiable since $f$ is so.

Also $\phi ^{'}(x)=e^x(f(x)+f^{'}(x))$

Now $\phi(x_1)=0,\phi(x_2)=0$

Since between any two roots of $\phi(x)$ lies one root of $\phi^{'}(x)$,
 so there exists $\xi \in(x_1,x_2)$ such that $\phi^{'}(\xi)=0$

Hence $e^\xi(f(\xi)+f^{'}(\xi))=0$

since $e^\xi\neq 0 $  so $f(\xi)+f^{'}(\xi)=0$

Answer (score 3):

If $x_1$ or $x_2$ is a multiple root then we can take $\xi = x_1$ or $\xi = x_2$, respectively. Otherwise, if $f'(x_1) < 0$ then $f'(x_2) > 0$, and vice versa. Try drawing it to understand why. Now we can use the intermediate value theorem for derivatives.

Comment: However, $f'(x)$ may be not continuous.

Comment: Darboux Theorem ensures that a derivative that changes sign attains a zero, irrespective of whether or not it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to say that $f$ is defined on $\left[ x_{1},x_{2}\right] $
(at least) such that $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})=0$ and $f(x)>0$ on the open $%
(x_{1},x_{2}).$ Moreover, $f$ is continously differentiable over (at least) $%
\left[ x_{1},x_{2}\right] .$ Show that there exists $\xi \in \left[
x_{1},x_{2}\right] $ such that $f(\xi )+f^{\prime }(\xi )=0.$

It suffices to show that $f^{\prime }(x_{1})\geq 0$ and $f^{\prime
}(x_{2})\leq 0.$ Then the function $g(x)=f(x)+f^{\prime }(x)$ is continous
on $\left[ x_{1},x_{2}\right] $ and $g(x_{1})=0+f^{\prime }(x_{1})\geq 0$
and $g(x_{2})=0+f^{\prime }(x_{2})\leq 0.$ Then by the intermediate value
theorem, there exists $\xi \in \left[ x_{1},x_{2}\right] $ such that $g(\xi
)=f(\xi )+f^{\prime }(\xi )=0.$

Now let us give a proof for $f^{\prime }(x_{1})\geq 0.$ Since $%
f(x)>0=f(x_{1})$ for $x>x_{1}$ then $f(x)-f(x_{1})>0$ and $x-x_{1}>0$ for
all $x>x_{1},$ then $\frac{f(x)-f(x_{1})}{x-x_{1}}>0$ for all $x>x_{1}$ and
by passing to the limit as $x$ tends to $x_{1}^{+}$ it follows that  $%
f^{\prime }(x_{1})=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{1}^{+}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_{1})}{x-x_{1}}%
\geq 0.$ Same proof for $f^{\prime }(x_{2})\leq 0.$

Comment: Is it legal to make so many assumptions? :D

Comment: I agree with you, but the problem statment is not clear, so i have tried to do my best! If he precise the set of assumptions I will arrange my proof accordingly! ''continously diff'' is too much, I beleive that it can be relaxed. BUt don't forget, he say no integration theory! That is we cannot use the Taylor thm with integral reminder for example!

Comment: Second answer with no additional assumption. 

Put $h(x)=e^{x}f(x),$ then $h$ is as $f$ has a derivative over the interval $%
\left[ x_{1},x_{2}\right] .$ 

Moreover, $h(x_{1})=e^{x_{1}}f(x_{1})=0,$ and $h(x_{2})=0.$ 

By Rolle's theorem, there exists $\xi \in \left( x_{1},x_{2}\right) $ such
that $h^{\prime }(\xi )=0.$ 

However, $h^{\prime }(\xi )=e^{\xi }(f(\xi )+f^{\prime }(\xi )).$ So, $f(\xi
)+f^{\prime }(\xi )=0$ since $e^{\xi }>0.$

Answer (score -1):

Real-valued differentiable function $f(x)$ attains equal zero values at two distinct points $x_1$ and $x_2.$ According with [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), so exists point $x_3$ with $f'(x_3)=0.$

If $f(x_3)=0$ that $x_3$ is required point. Consider the case $f(x_3)>0.$

If $f'(x_2)=0,$ that $x_2$ is required point. Let $r_0=x_2.$ If $f'(x_2)>0,$ then we have $f(x_2-\varepsilon)<0$ for sufficiently small epsilon and a root $r_1\in(x_3, x_2-\varepsilon)$ etc. If $f'(r_k)<0,$ then let $x_r=r_k,$ wherein $x_r\leq x_2$

$f(x)+f'(x)$ is continuos in $(x_3,x_r),$ wherein 
$$f(x_3)+f'(x_3)>0,\quad f(x_r)+f'(x_r)<0.$$
So there is a point $X\in(x_3, x_2)$ with $f(X)+f'(X)=0.$

Case $f(x_3)<0$ is proved.

Case $f(x_3)<0$ can be proved similarly.

Comment: "More strict" than *what*?

Comment: @Did Which is founded at  definitions, dear downvoter.

Comment: Other answers already were "founded at definitions", to use your lingo. Please do not smear other answerers to motivate that you post not-so-useful answers to old questions. (Unrelated: how do you know who votes what?)

Comment: @Did As you wish

Comment: @Did Are [these](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/297350/yuri-negometyanov?tab=reputation) correct?

Comment: Huh? What? $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Thank you.

Comment: When you will find the time to explain what you are up to, do not hesitate to explain yourself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Did I aspire to a result, but sometimes fond of. Criticism helps me, but I can not immediately understand it. Perhaps this is the main thing.

Comment: Indeed you seem to meet the greatest difficulties to understand the remarks made about your posts. My suggestion would be to concentrate on overcoming this, for the greater good of your answers, rather than diverting the discussion on downvotes and whatever other subjects one might imagine. Deal?

Comment: @Did I'm agree. Yes.